# Function undefined for onclick event -HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm just starting out working with the HTML5 canvas and I want to use `onclick` to call as `js` function in my document.

However, despite declaring the function in my JS, I still get `[function name] is not defined` when clicking.

The function is defined as such:

```
function draw_b() {
    var b_canvas = document.getElementById("b"); // finds the canvas in the DOM
    var b_context = b_canvas.getContext("2d"); // context for drawing. No 3D option yet
    b_context.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
}
```

The click event is included as such:

```
onclick="draw_b();return false"
```

Yet when I click the element, I get:

```
draw_b is not defined
```

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymtz11m0/2/)

Comment: You want to use `No Wrap - In Head` in jsFiddle. Also what is `document.getElementById("b")`, where is it defined? Maybe you mean `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSfiddle you need to use the `No Wrap - In <head>` option so the function is defined when used inline for the HTML elements. Also `var b_canvas = document.getElementById("b");` should be `var b_canvas = document.getElementById("a");`

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ymtz11m0/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong ID

```
var b_canvas = document.getElementById("a");// Use `a` not `b`
```

Answer (score -1):

Jsfiddle doesn't like `onclick=""` so you need to use `addEventListener` from JavaScript.

```js
var a_canvas = document.getElementById("a");

a_canvas.addEventListener("click",draw_b);

function draw_b() {
    var b_canvas = document.getElementById("b"); // finds the canvas in the DOM
    var b_context = b_canvas.getContext("2d"); // context for drawing. No 3D option yet
    b_context.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="a" width="300" height="225"></canvas>
<canvas id="b" width="300" height="225"></canvas>
```